# Can't log in to SQL server after cloning repo

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-core

I am using the generic ASP.NET Core sample project with login examples.  I made some basic modifications (no modifications to the model).

I pushed my project out to bitbucket and then cloned it on another computer (where I have a different login and domain).

When I try to load my project, I get the following:

> Cannot open database "aspnet-WebApp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" requested by the >. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'MYNEWDOMAIN\mynewusername'.

It's using EF migrations (since the example uses basic migrations).

I don't care about the content of the database (I seed it anyway)... I just want to be able to run the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ASP.NET or Entity Framework. But SQL Server authentication.

Comment: Well, the SQL server gets created the first time I run the project on the original machine, right?  And I have a Migrations folder, but in my Databases view the database doesn't exist (because it's not copied in the git clone).  So how do I get the database built again?

Comment: How the connection string looks like? Are you using LocalDd rather than 'real' SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it's a local database rather than a "real" server.  Where can I find the connection string?  I'm using the generic example.

Comment: "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: Are you able to access it from SQL Server Management Studio? Did you run VS under local admin (don't do it)? If you can access it then try to delete and recreate it. Also you can (re-)grant yourself the permissions.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to run Add-Migration and Update-Database.  The first time I ran the project on my original machine, the database was automatically created for me.

Comment: If anyone else runs into this problem, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Cool. Please post as an answer (and later accept it). Thanks!